# How to delete an integer value in a variable in python

Tags: python

I am currently creating a quiz program on python. After each question is selected by random.choice, I want the program to delete this question from the list so it cannot be asked twice. But the program does not delete the question number, so it can still be selected again. Here is my code:

```
questionNumbers = [1,2]
    questionChosen = random.choice(questionNumbers)
    if questionChosen == 1:
        del questionNumbers[questionNumbers.index(questionChosen)]
        q1 = "Who is John Von Neumann?"
        print(q1)
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

The best way would be to use `random.shuffle` on your original list to change item positions. Then `pop` them until there are no more items on your list

Example:

```
import random

questionNumbers = [1,2,3,4]

random.shuffle(questionNumbers)
while questionNumbers:
    print(questionNumbers.pop())
```

This prints `1,2,3,4` in a random order everytime.

Slightly more elaborate example with questions & answers as tuples in the list:

```
import random

questionNumbers = [("who killed Kennedy","Lee Harvey Oswald"),("Who starred in XXX","Vin Diesel")]  # sorry for the bad Q&A

random.shuffle(questionNumbers)
while questionNumbers:
    q,a = questionNumbers.pop()
    print("right" if input("{} ?".format(q))==a else "wrong")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `list.remove(item)` to remove an item from a list.

```
import random

questionNumbers = [1,2]
questionChosen = random.choice(questionNumbers)
if questionChosen == 1:
    questionNumbers.remove(questionChosen)
    q1 = "Who is John Von Neumann?"
    print(q1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend against explicitly deleting from the list - it's rare to actually use del. It's better to just figure out what you want to loop through ahead of time, and then loop through the list. You can randomly order the question numbers using `shuffle` from the `random` module, and then just loop through the shuffled list:

```
from random import shuffle

x = [1,2,3,4]
shuffle(x)

for q_num in x:
    print(q_num)
```